React native display [object Object] after returning it
I receive some string that containt html tags. Exemple : "Hello,click <u>here</u>"
I create a function for interpret them with the goal to render it under react native :
formating(text){
        // Define regular expressions to match HTML tags
        const boldRegex = /<b>(.*?)<\/b>/g;
        const italicRegex = /<i>(.*?)<\/i>/g;
        const underlineRegex = /<u>(.*?)<\/u>/g;
        const lineBreakRegex = /<br\s?\/?>/g;

        let formattedText = text
          .replace(boldRegex, (_, content) => <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{content}</Text>)
          .replace(italicRegex, (_, content) => <Text style={{ fontStyle: 'italic' }}>{content}</Text>)
          .replace(underlineRegex, (_, content) => <Text style={{ textDecorationLine: 'underline' }}>{content}</Text>)
          .replace(lineBreakRegex, () => <Text>{'\n'}</Text>);

        return  <Text>{formattedText}</Text>
    }

The problem is that when i display it in my application :
<View>
    {string.formating("my string")}
</View>

It render me "Hello,click [object Object]"
So the  in the return is well interpret and the problem come form the replace but impossible to find a solution.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Are want to show text something like this Hello Click here?

Yes exaclty, if here is between  as, in html, put it in bold

Probably, this answer can help.

Matching HTML with regex is a bad idea. You are better of parsing it and then replacing the tags...

The solution was to use reactStringReplace install with yarn add react-string-replace.
Here the new code :
formating(text) {
        const replacements = [
            { regex: /<b>(.*?)<\/b>/g, component: (match, i) => <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{match}</Text> },
            { regex: /<i>(.*?)<\/i>/g, component: (match, i) => <Text style={{ fontStyle: 'italic' }}>{match}</Text> },
            { regex: /<u>(.*?)<\/u>/g, component: (match, i) => <Text style={{ textDecorationLine: 'underline' }}>{match}</Text> },
            { regex: /<br\s?\/?>/g, component: (match, i) => <Text>{'\n'}</Text> }
        ];

        let formattedText = text;
        replacements.forEach(({ regex, component }) => {
            formattedText = reactStringReplace(formattedText, regex, component);
        });

        return <Text>{formattedText}</Text>;
    }

Thank you to @Wiktor Stribiżew for gave me this track.
